# iBeacon region monitoring after iPhone reboot

Tags: ibeacon

I'm using the 7.1.2 firmware.
Background location update is enabled in the plist.
iBeacon Region monitoring is working fine even when app is in background.

I was thinking region monitoring was automatically restarted after a phone reboot.
In my case, nothing appends after the reboot (I have wait 20 minutes)...